# How to popup the "enable access in privacy settings" view

Tags: ios, privacy

my question is quite simply, how can I popup the following view in my app?

[image: No Access To Photos Or Videos]

I've seen this in quite a lot of apps, so I believe this is a system-level view controller? But what is it? How can I show it in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that is NOT a system provided view.  You'll have to detect a denial of permission by the user, and then create a view to display.  Many people copy Apple's style for this view in order to make their apps 'blend in' with the platform, but its not directly provided to third party developers.

Comment: So I guess this is probably the "right" answer, thank you Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to pop this by yourself. Whenever you implement functionality that needs privacy settings, the OS asks the user if he would like to let your app to use this functionality (for example contacts or camera) automatically. If he denies to give access, then he will be presented with a view like this one whenever he tries to use that functionality again (unless of course if he has changed the settings manually in privacy settings).

Comment: Hi, I'm using enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:, and when I switch off the access to image in privacy settings, only the failure block is called, and this view is not showing. What am I missing?